# Wordpress query relationship between custom post types

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have two Custom Post Types: `Movies` and `Directors`

A Director owns many Movies.
A Director can be either an In-House or Freelance employee.

I'm using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) to make a radio group on the Director Post Type where you can set it to either In-House or Freelance.

I'm also using ACF to make a select box in the Movies Post Type where you select a Director and you get the Post Object in return.

**How do I make a query so I only get Movies where the Director is an In-House employee?**

Edit: I'll provide an example using plain SQL:

```
SELECT movies.name, directors.name
FROM movies JOIN directors ON directors.id = movies.director_id
WHERE directors.type LIKE '%In-House%'
```

Is there a better way of querying like this in Wordpress other than doing raw SQL?

Comment: You question is not understandable please describe it properly.

Comment: Fixed some minor formatting

Comment: Thank you. @siddhesh I've added an SQL example to illustrate the simple query that actually has to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop for movies you need something like the following:

```
<?php 
$inhouse = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'DIRECTOR_POST_TYPE_NAME',
    'meta_key' => 'SELECT_FIELD_NAME',
    'meta_value' => 'IN_HOUSE_FIELD_VALUE'
    )
));

?>
<?php if( $inhouse ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $inhouse as $ihdirector ): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $doctor->ID ); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_title( $ihdirector->ID ); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```